# How to configure squid for retrieving (and caching) directly my static resources?

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, squid, cache, reverse-proxy

I have an Apache/Tomcat/Spring tc Server running on CentOS EC2 VM.

I would like to install squid **on the same machine** as a proxy for retrieving (directly i.e. without forwarding the request to Apache/Tomcat) and caching static content ONLY identified by URIs :  /images, /css or /js.

Other URIs should be forwarded to the normal Web Server and not cached.

Since I am a newbie, I didn't find from squid documentation how to configure squid for this desired behavior (and if it is even possible).

Could you please help me and tell me how should I configure squid for this purpose?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

By default, it will cache all static content, the predicate

`hierarchy_stoplist cgi-bin ?`

Is on by default, and is designed to prevent dynamic pages from being cached.

You can create an acl like the following:

```
acl static_content urlpath_regex ^/images
acl static_content urlpath_regex ^/css
acl static_content urlpath_regex ^/js
```

Then apply like this:

```
no_cache deny !static_content
```

Not tested..